Nested child component's native (dragover) event blocked by parent [dndDraggable]
I'm working on an Angular app where I'm using AG-Grid inside a component (audit-questions-grid), and I also have ngx-drag-drop enabled on other elements in the layout (e.g., sections). However, I’m encountering an issue where AG-Grid’s native drag-and-drop functionality (specifically, row dragging) is not working when ngx-drag-drop is active on the outer container.
What I’m Trying to Do:
I want to use AG-Grid's drag-and-drop functionality to reorder rows within the grid.
ag-grid's row can be moved to other section too.
I also want to use ngx-drag-drop to manage drag-and-drop between different sections outside the AG-Grid component.
link of github-issue on ngx-drag-drop
github-issue
    <div class="section" *ngFor="let section of sections">
  <div [dndDraggable]="section" (dndMoved)="onDragged(section)">
    <h3>{{section.name}}</h3>
  </div>

    <div class="collapse mb-3" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed(section)">
            <app-grid-component [section]="section" [questions]="getQuestions(section)" [isPending]="editingAuditQuestions"
                (dragStart)="onQuestionDragStart(section)" (dragDrop)="onQuestionDragDrop(section, $event)"
                (openEditQuestionModal)="onOpenEditQuestionModal($event)" (removeQuestion)="onRemoveQuestion($event)">
            </app-grid-component>
        </div>
</div>

this is my app-grid-component
    <div class="drop" (dragstart)="onDragStart()" (dragover)="onDragOver($event)" (drop)="onDragDrop($event)">
    <ag-grid-angular class="w-100" domLayout="autoHeight" [rowData]="questions" [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
        [columnDefs]="columns" [rowDragManaged]="true" [suppressRowDrag]="false" [suppressRowClickSelection]="true" [suppressCellFocus]="true"
        [suppressMovableColumns]="true" [suppressContextMenu]="true" [overlayLoadingTemplate]="overlayLoadingTemplate" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
        (gridSizeChanged)="onGridSizeChanged($event)" (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)">
    </ag-grid-angular>
</div>

